# unable to call scope from my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, scope

I am new to ROR and learning using tutorials. While creating a cms for my blog I came across this error: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass.
I was trying to nest pages to my subjects so that when I view pages using subjects, I only see specific pages with the id of that subject only.
So, first I created a view pages link on subjects page. Code for the subject view:

```
<% @page_title = "Subjects"%>
<%= link_to("Back to menu", {:controller => 'access', :action => 'index'}, :class => 'action new') %>

<div class="subjects index">
  <h2>Subjects</h2>

  <%= link_to("Add New Subject", {:action => 'new'}, :class => 'action new') %>

  <div><%= pluralize(@subjects.size, 'subject')%> found</div>
  <table class="listing" summary="Subject list">
    <tr class="header">
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Visible</th>
      <th>Pages</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>

    <tr class="<% cycle('odd', 'even')%>">
      <td><%= subject.position %></td>
      <td><%= subject.name %></td>
      <td class="center"><%= status_tag(subject.visible)%></td>
      <td class="center"><%= subject.pages.size %></td>
      <td class="actions">
        <%= link_to("View Pages", {:controller => 'pages', :subject_id => subject.id}, :class => 'action view page') %>
        <%= link_to("Show", {:action=>'show', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action show') %>
        <%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :id=>subject.id}, :class => 'action edit') %>
        <%= link_to("Delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action delete') %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

Then I created a before action for :subject_id in my pages controller to find the subject with that id and then use that id to display pages. My pagescontroller code:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  layout "admin"

  before_action :confirm_logged_in
  before_action :find_subject

  def index
    #@pages = Page.sorted
    @pages = Page.where(:subject_id => @subject.id)
    #@pages = @subject.pages
  end

  def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new

    @page = Page.new(:subject_id => @subject.id)
    @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
    @page_count = Page.count + 1
  end

  def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params)
    if @page.save
      flash[:notice] = "Page created successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'index', :subject_id => @subject.id)
    else
      @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
      @page_count = Page.count + 1
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def edit
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
    @page_count = Page.count
  end

  def update
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    if @page.update_attributes(page_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Page updated successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @page.id, :subject_id => @subject.id)
    else
      @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
      @page_count = Page.count
      render('edit')
    end
  end

  def delete
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    page = Page.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Page destroyed successfully."
    redirect_to(:action => 'index', :subject_id => @subject.id)
  end


  private

    def page_params
      params.require(:page).permit(:subject_id, :name, :permalink, :position, :visible)
    end

    def find_subject
      if params[:subject_id]
      @subject = Subject.find(params[:subject_id])
      end
    end

end
```

I also defined a scope sorted in my page model to sort the pages according to their position.
Model code:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :subject
    has_many :sections
    has_and_belongs_to_many :editors, :class_name => "AdminUser"

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_length_of :name, :maximum => 255
  validates_presence_of :permalink
  validates_length_of :permalink, :within => 3..255
  # use presence_of with length_of to disallow spaces
  validates_uniqueness_of :permalink
  # for unique values by subject use ":scope => :subject_id"

    scope :visible, lambda {where(:visible=>true)}
  scope :invisible, lambda {where(:visible=>false)}
  scope :sorted, lambda {order("pages.position ASC")}
  scope :newest_first, lambda {order("pages.created_at ASC")}
  scope :search, lambda {|query|
    where (["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])
  }
end
```

But this scope doesn't seem to work when i use this as  @pages = Page.where(:subject_id => @subject.id).sorter or @pages = @subject.pages.sorted. It displays nothing when I use this and when I remove sorted as can be seen in the code above, I can see the pages correctly but not sorted. I Don't know why that is. But it works when I use @pages = Page.sorted. Removing sorted from the 2nd and 3rd command of index also came out of nowhere. I had no real explanation why I removed it.

Anyhelp here would be appreciated in explaining this occurence. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Do you still get the error when you comment out the before action?

Comment: Do you have `position` column in Page Model?

It seems `position` is column of Subject.